# How to implement jQuery UI autocomplete function to an input in a Modal appended after loading the document?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, z-index

I'm trying to bind the jQuery UI autocomplete function to a input element that was appended after loading the document. I've tried several solutions but still got stuck. I'm using the following code:

```
// When user click "Add" button to add a new networks value
$(".modal").on("click", ".add-network-value", function(e){
  input = '<input class="edit-input form-control autocomplete-input" type="text" name="'+ table_name + '" size="' + input_width +'">';        
  autocomp_opt={
    source: ["aaa","bbb","ccccc"]
  };
  item = '<div class="networks-item"></div>';
  input = $(input).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
  item = $(item).append(input);
  $(this).parents(".sub-content").append(item);
}
```

**Update**

Well, it turns out that the code itself is correct. The problem is that the input box is in a "modal" that has a higher z-index value than jQuery-ui's autocomplete div's z-index. You need to higher the z-index value of the jQuery-UI autocomplete CSS file or lower the z-index of the modal.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I have it working in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ginovva320/Gvx6H/ Does your console give you any error?

Comment: If possible, use **class** attribute and bind autocomplete like this - **$('.autocomplete-input', input).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);**. It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using jQuery UI autocomplete function on a "modal". The drop-down box added by the autocomplete module may have not displayed on the top of your modal but it actually gets created - that may be the reason why you cannot see the list.

Answer (score 0):

Are the Javascript variables `table_name` and `input_width` defined? And are the classes on the HTML defined correctly?

The following code should work,

HTML:

```
<div class="sub-content">
    <div class="modal">
        <button class="add-network-value">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="networks-item"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var table_name  = 'test';
var input_width = 10;
$(document).ready(function() {

    // When user click "Add" button to add a new networks value
    $(".modal").on("click", ".add-network-value", function(e){
        var input = '<input class="edit-input form-control autocomplete-input" type="text" name="'+ table_name + '" size="' + input_width +'">';        
        var autocomp_opt={
            source: ["aaa","bbb","ccccc"]
        };
        var item = '<div class="networks-item"></div>';
        input = $(input).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
        item = $(item).append(input);
        $(this).parents(".sub-content").append(item);
    });
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3DqU5/) for a Fiddle.